# Connecting to SAS libraries via ODBC

Tags: sas, odbc, rodbc, dsn

I am new to ODBC and trying to make a DSN in Windows ODBC administrator to call it from R using "RODBC" or similar R-packages.

I am able to find the "server name" and "database name" for anything on "SQL Server" driver. However, "SAS" driver does not let me find explicit names for server and database names. All I know is the URI where the data set is stored, also I can get the host name of the SAS server that stores the databases and its port. Is there a way to add it as a DSN or even call it directly from R? I have tried several permutations of these name and addresses but I constantly get the same error that odbc connection was not successful.

For example, after I followed the steps to add SAS server in ODBC administrator, and I used RODBC package in R, I got this result

> odbcConnect("mydbname")
>   [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNm95.png)] -1
>   Warning message:
>   In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=mydbname") : ODBC connection failed

Comment: SAS doesn't really have data base names and servers, its usually libraries and such. Are these sas7bdat files or files on a server? Are they CAS?

Comment: They are on a server (and I think originally they are sas7bdat files). and they are not CAS

Comment: Sorry, now out of my wheelhouse then. Good Luck! You may get better answers on communities.sas.com due to a higher SAS user base. If you have access to SAS you can call the R program from SAS perhaps?

Comment: yes, but i was looking for a more structural way around it, thanks anyways

Comment: R has packages, such as haven, that can read SAS datasets directly.  Why not just use that?

Comment: Show what you tried (I presume in odbcad32) and what error messages you got.  What version of SAS and bittedness of Windows ?

Comment: @Tom because the datasets are very huge. any alternative way of handling it is appreciated. Actually I want to access the sas database and use my R codes (and partly SQL codes)

Comment: @Richard my windows is 64 bit

Comment: Do you have a SAS/Share server started? Do you know how to connect to it?  If the data is large you would probably be better off loading it into a DBMS instead of using a statistical analysis software to house it.

Comment: @Tom I am connected to a server (and I suppose it should be through SAS/Share right?) . Could you give a reference on where to load the data in a DBMS? I don't know where to start.

Comment: "I suppose it should be through SAS/Share right?" - nope, SAS has a multitude of services and unless you know you do, you're probably not connecting to a  SAS/Share server... And SAS ODBC driver [could (last time I checked) only connect to SAS/SHARE, SPDS, or local sas7bdat files](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odbcdref/64777/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n01ugmh99e646vn19a7rzscg9dmy.htm). I'd suggest using SAS itself to get the data into a standard format (be it RDBMS, local CSV files), then read it from R.